# Nilradical under surjective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ and $S$ be rings, $f:R \to S$ be a surjective homomorphism. Prove that

i) $f(\mathrm{Nil}_*R) \subset \mathrm{Nil}_* S$ where $\mathrm{Nil}_*R = \sqrt{0}$ is the nilradical of $R$.

ii) There exists a surjective homomorphism from $R/ \mathrm{Nil}_*R$ to $S / \mathrm{Nil}_*S$.

I see the answer in here [$f(\mathrm{Nil}_{*}R)\subseteq\mathrm{Nil}_{*}S$ and there exists an epimorphism from $R/\mathrm{Nil}_{*}R$ to $S/\mathrm{Nil}_{*}S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578673/fnil-r-subseteq-nil-s-and-there-exist-an-epimorphism-from-r-nil-r) but I think it's wrong because if $R$ and $S$ are not commutative rings then inverse imagine of prime ideal is not prime ideal.

Comment: it's a definition, $Nil_* R$ is also called prime radical of $R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although as you point out (and as is discussed [at this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399579/inverse-image-of-prime-ideal-in-noncommutative-ring)), for a homomorphism $f: R\to S$ of noncommutative rings the preimage of a prime ideal need not be prime, if $f$ is *surjective* then it is.

Use the formulation that an ideal $P$ is prime if $aRb \subset P$ for all $a,b \in R$, and push elements around between $R$ and $S$, the key bit being that $$f(a)f(R)f(b) = f(a)Sf(b)$$ by surjectivity.

Comment: oh i understand, thank you @Ben

Comment: @TrươngThừaChí  you are welcome :)